# Unidentified variable after being declared

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting this error

```
Fatal error: Non-static method Connect::connect() cannot be called statically in D:\xampp\htdocs\Panel\core\init.php on line 63
```

Here is my code

```
<?php
class Connect{
    public $db_host = "localhost";
    public $db_user = "root";
    public $db_pass = "";
    public $db_name = "panel";

    public function connect(){
            if(mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass)){
                    if(mysql_select_db($db_name)){
                            return true;
                    }else{
                            die(mysql_error());
                    }
            }else{
                    die(mysql_error());
            }
            return false;
    }
}
?>
```

How do I make the function static?
I tried adding 'static' to the function scope, but I got another error

Thanks :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Feel the scope, young Skywalker, the scope is all around you.  Do not succumb to gobals, the dark side of the scope.

Comment: You should not be using `mysql_query` when writing new code. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from PHP.

Comment: Also, declare is for constants, which are enough like globals that you should forget about them for a while. That is not the scope you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass the variables to function as parameter

```
function connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass,$db_name)
```

And call this function as

```
connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass,$db_name);
```

**Edit**

By seeing your pastebin, you are calling class variables, you have to use `$this->variale_name` to access them.

```
<?php
class Connect{
    public $db_host = "localhost";
    public $db_user = "root";
    public $db_pass = "";
    public $db_name = "panel";

    public function connect(){
            if(mysql_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass)){
                    if(mysql_select_db($this->db_name)){
                            return true;
                    }else{
                            die(mysql_error());
                    }
            }else{
                    die(mysql_error());
            }
            return false;
    }
}
?>
```

## PDO

```
<?php
class Connect{
    private $db_host = "localhost";
    private $db_user = "root";
    private $db_pass = "";
    private $db_name = "panel";
    private $dbh = false;
    public function connect(){
        if ($this->dbh === false)
            $this->dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->db_host.';dbname='.$this->db_name, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
        return $this->dbh;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Non-static method Connect::connect() cannot be called statically in D:\xampp\htdocs\Panel\core\init.php on line 63. Code: http://pastebin.com/KcjnMYLX

Comment: @Isaac show how you use the class. Connect::connect() is not the way to use that class. Your question doesn't even show a class.

Comment: @Chris I edited it to a class though. Look in the code. Im not very good at object oriented PHP :P

Comment: @Isaac Don't turn this into two or three questions, we aren't writing your code for you - learn. I'll help with that. Go back to the code in your question, use this correct answer to fix your original problem, go from there. Master one thing at a time.

Comment: @Yogesh you'll spoil the kid! :p How about some PDO, If you're in the mood to write code! Or constructor args for the options?

Comment: @Chris Ok. let me give 10 minutes. :)

Comment: You'll get my +1 back if you write PDO. Sample in one of my recent answers, if you need it :)

Comment: Well, I fixed it. http://pastebin.com/bLJ1x08m I cant awnser though, dont have enough reputation, so someone can piost that code and Ill accept it

Comment: @Isaac If you refer my answer it is correct one if you want Object oriented pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the variables inside the function like this

```
<?php

function connect(){

    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_user = "root";
    $db_pass = "";
    $db_name = "panel";

    if(mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass)){
        if(mysql_select_db($db_name)){

        }else{
            die(mysql_error());
        }
    }else{
        die(mysql_error());
    }
}
?>
```

Or you can pass the parameters in the function like this

```
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "panel";

connect($db_host,$db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

function connect($db_host,$db_user, $db_pass, $db_name){


        if(mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass)){
            if(mysql_select_db($db_name)){

            }else{
                die(mysql_error());
            }
        }else{
            die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: +1 on a good answer, but can you work PDO in? Pretty easy change to the answer to show how it is done.

Answer (score -1):

```
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "panel";
```

These variables are global and can't be accessible in function connect. If you have to use these global variables then use keyword `global` . Then these vars will be available within the function.

```
 function connect(){
        global $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name ;
        if(mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass)){
            if(mysql_select_db($db_name)){

            }else{
                die(mysql_error());
            }
        }else{
            die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Globals are always bad advice.